# iphone UiImage irregular cropping - JIGSAW puzzle

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

Am developing jigsaw puzzle for iphone. Here I have done the enough googling but i couldn't find any idea and code for **How to crop the uiimage in  irregular shap**. for example pls check the below URL.

http://www.jigzone.com/puzzles/AA055D504773?z=1

If Any sample code and suggestion would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bezier paths` you can create a `path` of any shape you like and apply that as the `clipping path` for part of the image, so if you put the result into another image with a transparent background you would have created one piece of your puzzle. You have to come up with a way to create lots of pieces that fit together, but then of course that is the whole point of your app, so I think it is fair that you figure that one out yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for response richard: Yes i have a workaround how to proceed after cropping the image. Cropping is the one which stopped me in process. Is there any code sample in the bezier paths concept ? am bit new to it

Comment: I'd start by reading Apple's documentation on UIBezierPath. There are underlying Core Graphics calls you can make for really fancy drawing but for just outlining a piece of an image the higher level `UIBezierPath` is fine.